# Setting width of a span to 0 if the link is visited?

Tags: css, hyperlink, width, visited

As the title says I'm trying to set the width of a span once the link has been visited. The reason for this is that we are supposed to display " New! " tag next to a thread but it should disappear once the link is visited.
They do not want to use cookies to track the user so I came up with a idea to set display or visibility to none on a:visited. That does not work because of security issues.

**What worked for me was setting the background and text color to white (I know it's not the right way to do it).**

Now they want to move this tag to the beginning of the thread title. This creates a problem of blank space in front of the title (As new! is still there its just all white). I though I might simply set the width to 0 and that would work. It doesn't. Any solutions ?

Comment: Can you include your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
span:visited
{ 
display:none;
}
```

Or with jquery:

```
$('span:visited').hide();
```

Comment: I can do it with jQuery, I'm just trying to avoid it.

Comment: Just had that as a option, you can use the first option to do the same thing though.